# How to update the elasticsearch client properly

Tags: elasticsearch, debian, deb

The version of the Elasticsearch client on my production server is 1.1.1

I need to update it because I had to use a function like "field_value_factor" which is not supported in this specific version. It's not a problem to loose the existing indexes. This is the commands lines I have imagined :

- /etc/init.d/elasticsearch stop
- dpkg -r elasticsearch
- dpkg -i elasticsearch-1.4.1.deb
- update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10

What do you think ?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to upgrade ElasticSearch itself - check out the upgrade docs on this (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html) as well as any breaking changes (at the same URL).

Comment: The rolling upgrade allows the ES cluster to be upgraded one node at a time with no observable downtime for end users. It's not an issue actually, there will be a temp page while the service is being updated. So if I execute 'dpkg -i elasticsearch-1.4.1.deb', it will replace the current installation ?